# how to extract the string using regular expressions

Tags: string-manipulation, filtering, regular-expressions

I have the list :

```
a1 = {"struct name1 {","struct name2{","struct name3{","struct name4{",
      "struct name5{","struct lastStruct{"}
```

I tried to extract the struct names `"name1",..."lastStruct"` with this but I failed hard :(

```
StringCases[a1, RegularExpression["[^struct^{^\\s]"]]
```

Which returned:

> {{"n", "a", "m", "e", "1"}, {"n", "a", "m", "e", "2"}, {"n", "a", "m", "e", "3"}, 
>        {"n", "a", "m", "e", "4"}, {"n", "a", "m", "e", "5"}, {"l", "a", "S"}}

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Regular expressions, as requested:

```
StringCases[a1, RegularExpression["struct (.*)[ ]*\{"] :> "$1"]
```

(* {{"name1 "}, {"name2"}, {"name3"}, {"name4"}, {"name5"}, {"lastStruct"}} *)

Comment: i will check the solution tomorrow.Thanx

Comment: thanx , this solved it and is shorter as hailrutan's solution

Comment: what does ":> "$1"" do :) ?

Comment: @timoftebogdan It refers to the first matched substring enclosed in parenthesis `(.*)`

Comment: damn , this stuff is freaky :(

Comment: this doesn't work with `StringCases["struct name5{", 
 RegularExpression["struct (.*)[ ]"] :> "$1"]` so I added the other answer as correct which works with it

Comment: @timoftebogdan Your test is wrong. You surely modified my code.

Comment: @timoftebogdan And that was the last time I spent my time in helping you. You need to learn some manners. Have a nice day.

Comment: ok I checked it back and it seems to be working , also the first guy I think he translated the Mathematica String expression to regular expression using StringPattern`PatternConvert ...that's sneaky lol

Answer (score 6):

You can use the high-level functions to build your string expression for this:

```
StringCases[a1, "struct " ~~ name__ ~~ "{" :> name]
(* {{"name1 "}, {"name2"}, {"name3"}, {"name4"}, {"name5"}, {"lastStruct"}} *)
```

If you really need a `RegularExpression` then there is nothing simpler than starting with the high-level functions and let *Mathematica* figure out the dirty details :-)

Observe:

```
StringPattern`PatternConvert["struct " ~~ name__ ~~ "{"]
(* {"(?ms)struct (.+)\\{", {{Hold[name], 1}}, {}, Hold[None]} *)
```

What you see in the first position of the resulting list is what you need:

```
StringCases[a1, RegularExpression["(?ms)struct (.+)\\{"] :> "$1"]
(* {{"name1 "}, {"name2"}, {"name3"}, {"name4"}, {"name5"}, {"lastStruct"}} *)
```

Comment: sorry , but I need to use regular expressions like I stated in the title

Comment: @timoftebogdan See the update.

Comment: @timoftebogdan Btw, I saw just now that I ignored that there is a space after "name1". I guess you can now fix this yourself, right?

Comment: i will check the solution tomorrow.Thanx